# crear el número de elementos div obtenidos del campo de entrada

Tags: javascript

tengo este código. No consigo que al escribir en el input un numero entre el 1 y el 7 y ejecutar la función mostrar me aparezcan el numero de divs que escribes en el input(por ejemplo si escribes 5 en el input que aparezcan 5 divs).

PD: soy nuevo en esto

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/estilos/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <section></section>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer>

    <input type="number" id="num_coches" placeholder="Escribe un número">
    <input type="button" onclick="fmostrar()" value="Mostrar" id="butt">
    <input type="button" value="Empezar" onclick="fstart()" id="empezar">
    
    </footer>

    <script src="assets/script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ];

function fmostrar() {
   
    let numero = document.getElementById("num_coches").value;
    let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    nav.innerHTML = '';

    let html = "";
    for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        html+= "<div>" + array[i] + "</div>";
    }

document.querySelector("nav").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Creo que la variable `array` es innecesaria ya que el ciclo debería de ser `i < numero ` según tu enunciado. Y concatenas la variable `i` entre los divs.

Comment: buenas, si quito el array y cambio solo se muestra 1 div, y dentro de el div se muestra el numero que introduzco en el input, lo que necesito es que al introducir 1 numero en el input se creen la cantidad de divs igual a ese numero

Comment: Y que valor tiene numero?

Comment: el numero que le introduces tu en el input, la cosa es que tu tienes que introducir un numero en el input entre el 1 y 6 que son los elementos del array pero tu puedes poner 4 o 2 o 5 en vez de los 6

Answer (score 2):

solo basta un pequeño cambio a tu código para que funcione, como es cambiar en el ciclo el que vaya hasta el numero que quieres, i.e:  `i < array.length` por `i < numero` esto hace que recorras el vector el numero de veces que indicas en el **input**

```js
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ];

function fmostrar() {
   
    let numero = document.getElementById("num_coches").value;
    let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    nav.innerHTML = '';

    let html = "";
    for( let i = 0; i < numero; i++ ){
        html+= "<div>" + array[i] + "</div>";
    }

document.querySelector("nav").innerHTML = html;
}
```

para que lo puedas visualizar mejor te dejo este css para que lo veas más facil

```
  width: 60px
}
nav>div{ /* le da un borde y separa internamente del borde por 2 pixeles, además tambien separa externamente de los otros elementos por 4 pixeles */
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 2px;
  margin:4px;
}
```

ahora puedes mejorar tu código mucho más (esto ya fue indicado por @javdromero) una de las formas de mejorarlo es eliminar el vector luego concatenar a tu cadena el contador del ciclo y no el elemento del vector, luego también puedes agregar una condición que nos diga si el numero se encuentra entre 1 y 7

```js
function fmostrar() {
   
    let numero = document.getElementById("num_coches").value;
    let nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    nav.innerHTML = '';

    let html = "";
    if(numero >= 1 && numero < 7 )
    {
      for( let i = 0; i < numero; i++ ){
          html+= "<div>" + i + "</div>";
      }
      
    } else {
      html = "el número sobrepasa el intervalo"
    }

document.querySelector("nav").innerHTML = html;
}
```

puedes ver el código funcionando en [aquí](https://codepen.io/Brian-Bustos/pen/oNmBZpz)

Comment: muchas gracias, agradecido.

Comment: de nada no te olvides indicar que la respuesta fue correcta o que te ayudo

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo la función [*createElement()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) porque es excelente para crear elementos, ya que es un método simple y muy eficiente para generar nuevos elementos.

Para utilizar la función createElement(), simplemente pasa el nombre del elemento que deseas crear como argumento y utiliza un div como padre, el cual tendrá hijos.

De esta manera,

```js
  let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

function fmostrar() {
  let numero = document.getElementById("num_coches").value;
  let nav = document.querySelector("nav");

 
  nav.innerHTML = "";

  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let divElement = document.createElement("div")
    divElement.classList.add(`classe-${i}`);//add class
    divElement.textContent = array[i];

 
   nav.appendChild(divElement);//adiciona filho ao pai
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/estilos/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <section></section>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer>

    <input type="number" id="num_coches" placeholder="Escribe un número">
    <input type="button" onclick="fmostrar()" value="Mostrar" id="butt">
    <input type="button" value="Empezar" onclick="fstart()" id="empezar">
    
    </footer>

    <script src="assets/script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> La ventaja de usar el createElement es que permite agregar propiedades
> a div, como clase e ID. Es más adecuado para elementos DOM HTML y es
> más seguro en cuanto a seguridad, ya que la función createElement()
> previene la inyección de código malicioso, a diferencia del operador
> `+=`, que no cuenta con esa protección.

En código que se proporcionó, lo que se estaba haciendo era crear una `string` y asignarla a la propiedad innerHTML del elemento nav. Cuando el valor superaba 6, mostraba *undefined*. Con createElement, se crearán cada elemento individualmente y se adjuntarán al elemento nav.